# Prove the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}} = \frac{1}{x^{^{2}} -1}$ exists.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, epsilon-delta

For each of the following, use definitions (rather than limit theorems) to prove that the limit exists. Identify the limit in each case.

(c) $\lim_{x\rightarrow-1^{+}} = \frac{1}{x^{^{2}} -1}$

Proof:  By definition the function f(x) is said to converge to infinity as x → a if and only if there is an open interval I containing and given a real M, there is an δ > 0 such that 0 < |x - a| < δ implies f(x) > M, in which case f(x) approaches infinity as x → a.

Let L = infinity, and suppose ε > 0. And suppose M > 0. Then there is an δ > 0 such that |x - (- 1) | < ε . Then choose M = 
Can someone please help me prove the limit exists. I don't know how to continue.
Please, I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure this limit exists? I guess you are trying prove the limit exists for $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{x^2-1}$.

Comment: That is the problem. It is stated exactly as the book. The limit has to do with infinity.

Comment: So you have to prove that the limt is $\infty$? And the limit approaches $1$ or $-1$?

Comment: Yes, but I have to use the definition and choose an M.

Comment: Work backwards, choose $M$ and figure out how close $x$ must be to $-1$ (and in $(-1,\infty)$) so that $f(x) >M$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any $\;M\in\Bbb R^+\;$ and $\;x>-1\;$ (but very close to $\;-1\;$)

$$\frac1{|x^2-1|}>M\iff x+1<\frac1{M|x-1|}<\frac1{2M}\implies$$

since we can make sure that $\;|x-1|>\frac32\iff\frac1{|x-1|}<\frac23\;$ , so  we can choose $\;\delta_M:=\frac2{3M}\;$ , and thus:

$$x+1<\delta_M\implies\left|\frac1{x^2-1}\right|>M$$

and the above proves

$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac1{x^2-1}=-\infty$$

since $\;x<-1\implies x^2-1<0\;$

Comment: Is that δ_M mean it depends on M?  Also it is not necessary to mention ε?

Comment: Are you assuming M = |x + 1|?

Comment: To prove $$\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=\infty$$ you must prove that for any $\;M\in\Bbb R\;$ there exists $\;\delta_m>0\;$ s.t. $$x-x_0<\delta_m\implies f(x)>M$$ This is what's been done above.

Comment: And no:I'm not assuming $\;|x+1|=M\;$ at all. How could I and where did you get this idea from?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I got confused since I thought |x^2 - 1| could be factored to |(x+1)(x-1)|.

Comment: @user21986, and it is true that it can be factored that way and that's one of the things I used in the above...

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Timbuc can be used to take care of the required estimates, so the material below consists only of preliminary comments.

You are asked to prove that $\lim_{x\to -1^+} \frac{1}{x^2-1}$ exists. Draw a number line, with $x=-1$ on it, also probably $x=0$, and maybe $x=1$.

First we try to find out what's going on. We are approaching $-1$ *from the right*.  Imagine $x$ a tiny bit *bigger* than $-1$, like $-0.99999$. What can we say about $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$? The number $x^2$ is then close to $1$, but **less** than $1$. So $x^2-1$ is close to $0$, but **negative**. It follows that $\frac{1}{x^2-1}$ is "large negative."

The way some people use limit language, that means the limit does not exist. Other people say that the limit "is" $-\infty$. It looks as if in your course "infinite" limits are allowed.  We want to prove that
$$\lim_{x\to -1^+}\frac{1}{x^2-1}=-\infty.$$
So we want to prove that for any positive $M$, there is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $-1\lt x\lt -1+\delta$, then $\frac{1}{x^2-1}\lt -M$. (The $L$ and $\epsilon$ stuff in the post should be deleted.)

The estimates by Timbuc can now be used.

Comment: Yes sir, you are right. I edited the end of  my answer. Thanks. +1